# Unable to display <div> over YouTube in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, youtube, z-index

On the media pages of my (test) website http://www.corryderek.nl/mkh/media.php?item=2014_09_2 there are three navigation arrows: left (previous film), up (list of films) and right (next film). These are displayed with color brown behind the film and should appear with color ochre in front of the film when the user moves the mouse over the film. The film and background arrows have a z-index of 40 and the ochre-colored navigation arrows of 50. This works except on IE (I have tested IE11/Windows 7 and IE8/Windows XP).

Probably for the same reason, an IE user cannot click on the navigation arrows in the film area. I allow the arrows to protrude a little from the film so that IE users can still access them, but how can I persuade IE to respect the z-index values? I found the trick with `wmode=opaque` and that makes the arrows visible, but the mouse still doesn't get through.

The site is in Dutch but should be easy enough to navigate. **Vorige**, **Lijst** and **Volgende** mean Previous, List and Next; **Beeld en Geluid** means Pictures and Sounds.

You can see the page outside its iframe on http://www.corryderek.nl/mkh/mediapages/2014_09_2.html

The relevant HTML is:

```
<div class="media_image"> 
 <img class="nav_up" src="../images/up_b.png" alt="">
 <img class="nav_left" src="../images/left_b.png" alt="">
 <img class="nav_right" src="../images/right_b.png" alt="">
 <iframe class="youtube_512" 
         src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FeBDi0GBjxw?wmode=opaque&rel=0&disablekb=1&showinfo=0"
         allowfullscreen=""
         frameborder="0">
 </iframe>
 <div class="nav_holder">
  <a href="../media.php" target="_parent">
   <img class="nav_up" src="../images/up.png" alt="Lijst" title="Lijst">
  </a>
  <a id="leftkey" href="../media.php?item=2014_09_1" target="_parent">
   <img class="nav_left" src="../images/left.png" alt="Vorige" title="Vorige">
  </a>
  <a id="rightkey" href="../media.php?item=2014_10_1" target="_parent">
   <img class="nav_right" src="../images/right.png" alt="Volgende" title="Volgende">
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS is:

```
.media_image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 40;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav_holder {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.media_image:hover .nav_holder {
  display: block;
}
.nav_up {
  border: 0px solid ;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.nav_left {
  border: 0px solid ;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nav_right {
  border: 0px solid ;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 0px;
}
.youtube_512 {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  width: 512px;
  height: 288px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Thanks for any hints or insights,

--- Derek

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding `wmode=transparent` to the url:

```
<iframe class="youtube_512" 
     src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FeBDi0GBjxw?wmode=transparent&rel=0&disablekb=1&showinfo=0"
     allowfullscreen=""
     frameborder="0">
```

Comment: `wmode=transparent` and `wmode=opaque` appear the same; transparent is apparently more CPU-intensive but I haven't done any measurements. Either makes the arrows visible, neither makes them clickable.

Comment: For me this option works fine in All IE browsers. Maybe try playing around with e.g. `z-index`. Are you sure the buttons are clickable when the video is not there? If they are visible, they are on top of the video. Which means that if you click them, any click event on them should fire. Does clicking the arrows pause the video? Are you sure that the click event is valid? Maybe the click-event is fired, but there is an error in your JavaScript..? I browsed your page with IE 11 (and via the console tried IE8-10) and the arrows work fine for me...

Comment: Thanks for your help; I'm not sure if you're seeing what I see. In IE the ochre arrows only become visible (and clickable) when I move the mouse pointer over the brown arrows, outside the film. I can then move the mouse back inside the film and they remain active. In Firefox etc they become visible (and active) as soon as the pointer is in the film. Thus if I place the pointer in the center of the film the navigation arrows are visible in Firefox etc; not in IE.

Comment: I have found that setting the z-index of the arrows to 50 (CSS entries nav_up, nav_left, nav_right) works better but then the brown arrows are always visible. (Of course I can change the images so that the brown arrows are transparent where the film will come, but then I cannot use a size other than 512x288, and I may want to use photos instead of films in the future).

Comment: The test links above won't work any more; we went live with Z-index 50 and modified brown arrows. I'd still love to find a definitive answer.